# Visual Studio 2015 Data Source Connection Properties Server List Issue

Tags: sql, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, connection-string, reporting

I am trying to connect VS to a specific data source for a reporting project however when I go to build the connection the server name is not visible. Is there a component missing that needs to be installed for this? It's been a hot minute since I resolved this same issue so my memory is a little fuzzy. I can't connect to the server in Management Studio either.

VisualStudioError.

[image: VisualStudioError]

ManagementStudioError.

[image: ManagementStudioError]

Comment: You can just type the name of the server into the dialog. Don't let the fact that you cannot browse for SQL Server instances on the network slow you down.

Comment: Could be a permission issue?

Comment: Am guessing you also had looked at Network Servers tab as well. If you do know the server details, you can just type in it as Richard suggested.

Comment: When I look through the Network Servers tab there are servers listed however none of the specific ones I am looking for are in the list and I cant connect to them.  Even when I just type the name in it wont connect via Win Authentication or using a proven account for SQL Authentication.